# Confirm and enable users in ASP.NET identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity, two-factor-authentication

I an working on an ASP.NET MVC project and   I want users to be disabled initially on registration until they confirm their email and phone number. But however (by default) disabled users cannot login to the app to do this unless by an admin. How can I temporarily disable  the users and still allow them login but only with limited access until they confirm their email and phone number.

Comment: In my app, I automatically send an email confirmation link when the user account is created. If they fail to click the link before it expires, a new link is sent when they try to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Customer Action Filters which in turn check whether user has verified mobile number or email address from database. 
Example of Action Filters is [Authorize] attribute on Controller.

You can then use this Customer Action Filters on Controller where you want to restrict them for doing any operation.

You can even display different view or Alert Message for telling users about it.

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Action Filters MSDN](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)